# How to count unique ids if certain columns have no missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df

```
ID   date    v1   v2  v3   v4  v5  v6
A     ..      1   2   3   NaN NaN NaN 
A     ..      0   2  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
B     ..      0   2   4    5   3   9
B     ..      2   6   6    6   3  NaN
D     ..      2  NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN
D     ..      9   2   2   NaN NaN NaN
D     ..      2   2   6    6   1   2
```

I want to extract rows whose columns (from v1-v5) aren't missing.

desired output

```
ID   date    v1   v2  v3   v4  v5  v6
B     ..      0   2   4    5   3   9
B     ..      2   6   6    6   3  NaN
D     ..      2   2   6    6   1   2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with a subset:

```
cols = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5']
df2 = df.dropna(subset=cols)
```

Or, use [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) combined with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
cols = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5']

df2 = df[df[cols].notna().all(axis=1)]
```

Alternative if v1-v5 are consecutive:

```
df2 = df[df.loc[:, 'v1':'v5'].notna().all(axis=1)]
```

output:

```
  ID date  v1   v2   v3   v4   v5   v6
2  B   ..   0  2.0  4.0  5.0  3.0  9.0
3  B   ..   2  6.0  6.0  6.0  3.0  NaN
6  D   ..   2  2.0  6.0  6.0  1.0  2.0
```